# Copy elision and temporary bound-by-ref object

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++ draft states:

> 12.8p31 This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> (...)
>
> - when a temporary class object that **has not been bound to a reference** (12.2) would be copied/moved
>     to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

In other words:

```
X MakeX() {
   return X(); // Copy elided
}

X MakeX() {
   const X& x = X(); // Copy not elided
   return x;
}
```

**What is the reason for such restriction for references**?

*Please do not focus on the validity of the following examples, as they are just to exemplify that I fail to see the difference (IMHO) between temporary and a reference*.

On one hand by introduction of reference we allowed other peers to alias the same object, while the caller of `MakeX()` expects it to be safe and clean.

```
class Y {
public:
    Y(const X& x) : _xRef(x) {}
private:
    const X& _xRef;
};

X MakeX() {
    const X& x = X();
    Y y{x};
    StaticStuff::send(y);
    return x; // Oops, I promised to return a clean,
              // new object, but in fact it might be silently
              // changed by someone else. 
}
```

But what about such case (probably it's UB ;)):

```
class Y {
public:
    Y(X* x) : _xPtr(x) {}
private:
    X* _xRef;
};

X MakeX() {
    X x;
    Y y{&x}; // I'm referencing a local object but I know it will be
             // copy elided so present in the outer stack frame.
    StaticStuff::send(y);
    return x; // Copy elided?
}
```

Comment: `StaticStuff::send(y);` does not actually introduce the possibility to modify `x` indirectly => it's Undefined Behavior to use a reference to `x` after the end of `MakeX`.

Comment: `Oops, I promised to return a clean, new object, but in fact it might be silently changed by someone else.` - what do you mean? `x` is `const X&` therefore not changeable.

Comment: your second version of `MakeX` would probably invoke the copy constructor to turn the `const X&` into a plain `X`, is that the problem you have?

Comment: @MatthieuM. In a way I expected UB, but I used this argument that even for NRVO programmer can do dirty stuff, so why to restrict the references.

Comment: @BЈовић Apart from having not-really-than-non-observable const (which s probably your fault) I meant that when you see `X func()` you expect that no one is able to reference this value as you will be the first one to get it (as you expect the value to be a copy).

Comment: @didierc Yup, that's what I want to avoid and I am asking why the restriction leading to a copy.

Answer (score 3):

You never *know* that a copy will be elided. Copy elision is never mandatory.

Therefore, either both cases are UB, or none. It depends on what `StaticStuff:send` does with the object you pass in. If it retains any poitner/reference to `y._xRef` or `*y._xPtr`, then dereferencing that pointer/reference after `MakeX()` has returned will indeed cause UB, as the original object `x` was one with automatic storage duration inside `MakeX()` and its lifetime has now ended.

It's possible that the result of this UB will be "everything works just fine" because copy ellision did take place and the pointer/reference refers to the instance in the "outer stack frame." However, this is pure coincidence and it's still UB.

Comment: Sure the standard states that "The elision (...) is *permitted*" so I can't expect anything, and yes, in those two cases I tread into UB-land. What I wanted to say is that I don't see a particular reason why const ref (which is the only way to keep temporaries) is not allowed, while a temporary is.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct, at least not in C++11. What if `X` is move-constructible but not copy-constructible? Then, the OP's first example would still compile and the compiler will be forced t do a `move elision`, right?
Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609968/is-default-constructor-elision-assignment-elision-possible-in-principle for details

Comment: @leden I don't quite follow. There is **no** way to **force** a copy/move elision to happen. Those are *always* optional.

Comment: @Angew: How about this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/452d037e9c21741d It doesn't elide the copy, but the copy is "promoted" to move because the lvalue is not used elsewhere and has no side effect?

Comment: @leden How is this related? As per 12.8/32, *any time* elision is possible, an lvalue must first be "tried" as an rvalue, and only be used as an lvalue when that fails (i.e. `return x;` always tries to move `x` first, and copies it if that's not possible). Then, the copy or move can optionally (at the compiler's sole discretion) be elided.