# Call different constructor conditionally

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to call different constructor of the same class depending on a run time condition. The constructor uses different initialization list (a bunch of things after `:`) so I can't process the condition within the constructor.

For example:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    bool condition = true;
    if (condition) {
        // The object in the actual code is not a std::vector.
        std::vector<int> s(100, 1);
    } else {
        std::vector<int> s(10);
    }
    // Error: s was not declared in this scope
    s[0] = 1;
}
```

I guess I can use pointer.

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    bool condition = true;
    std::vector<int>* ptr_s;
    if (condition) {
        // The object in the actual code is not a std::vector.
        ptr_s = new std::vector<int>(100, 1);
    } else {
        ptr_s = new std::vector<int>(10);
    }
    (*ptr_s)[0] = 1;
    delete ptr_s;
}
```

Is there a better way if I didn't write a move constructor for my class?

Comment: But it is not a std::vector. It is a class that I write. That is just for an example.

Comment: Well pardon the obvious. why use `std::vector` as an example then. It obviously has methods that could make this task easily doable. Regardless, does your *real* class support move-assignment or swapping?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I think i saw something like using ternary operator somewhere, but I am not sure. No, the class is a composition of a bunch of classes and most of them has no move constructor.

Comment: Well yeah, a ternary operator (used *twice* in this example), would work. it would be a little cryptic to read, but sure. `std::vector<int> v((condition?100:10), (condition?1:0));`. Your coworkers will *hate* you for this, btw, so honestly, reconsider this.

Comment: In your example you are calling the same constructor, but with different values, this case is easier that using different constructors because you can save the values you want to pass in the constructor in some temp variables and after the if else statement construct your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is to create a class that the default contructor does not make the allocations, computing ( and all the hard job ) but instead, have one function for example `initialize` and overload it for each constructor type to do the real job.

For example:

```
int main() {
    bool condition = true;
    SomeClass object;
    if (condition) {
        object.initialize(some params 1)
    } else {
        object.initialize(some params 2)
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may want the default constructor to do something meaningful in that case make a constructor that takes an object of a certain "dummy" type e.g. `DoNothing` and have instead:

```
 SomeClass object(DoNothing())
```

Comment: Be wary that this breaks RAII principle and has some repercussions. I.e. A freshly constructed object is not ready to use, and you should guard against it. Ensuring correctness using this approach complicates the design, and introduces lots of bolierplate for checks (or involves writing exceptions for calling methods on an uninitialized object).

Comment: @luk32 The last part of the answer helps a little on this matter, I believe, because the user kinda explitly demands "lazy" initialization. But generally of course one must use this carefully.

Comment: @luk32 what are some alternatives? Initializing the class requires reading lots of data from the hard disk, and then synchronizing the data between the objects created by the two constructors. I hard 2nd initialization is not the best case, but don't know the alternatives. Copy constructor is bad in this case. I guess writing lots of move constructors is the only choice?

Comment: hopefully cop elision works if I use optimization. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959846/move-semantics-in-eigen

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something along the lines of

```
std::vector<int> ptr_s;
if (condition) {
    ptr_s.resize(100);
} else {
    ptr_s.resize(10);
}
```

?

Comment: it is not a std:vector in the actual code. so i can't

Comment: Why don't you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with your real code then?

Comment: because the real code is too long. and then someone will say write move constructor. which will take a long time for the actual code. it means writing move constructor for the class and every class that makes up the class.

Comment: That is where the "simple" part of SSCCE comes in. Simplify the real code down to the point where it illustrates the problem and nothing more, then post that.